# C Multithreading | Thread creation in for loop uses args from last iteration

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, mutex

I'm new to multithreading and not the best in C in general so bare with me.

I have a for loop that creates a number of threads to which I'm passing arguments as such:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS; i++) {

    int ordered_product = (rand() % NO_OF_PRODUCTS);
    int ordered_quantity = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    int customer = (rand() % NO_OF_CUSTOMERS);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", customer+1, ordered_quantity, ordered_product+1);

    ThreadArgs myargs = {customer, ordered_product, ordered_quantity};

    int rc = pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, thread_function, &myargs);
    if(rc != 0) {
      perror("Pthread create");
      exit(1);
    }

  }
```

and I have the function "thread_function" which is written as such:

```
void* thread_function(void* arg) {

  ThreadArgs* args = (ThreadArgs*) arg;
  ThreadArgs myargs = *args;
  int customer_id = myargs.customer_id + 1;
  int product_quantity = myargs.product_quantity;
  int product_id = myargs.product_id +1;

  printf("Customer %d purchased %d of Product %d\n", customer_id, product_quantity, product_id);

  //pthread_exit(NULL)   // I tried this too...
  return NULL;
}
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
4 8 4
3 3 9
8 1 9
Customer 8 purchased 1 of Product 9
Customer 8 purchased 1 of Product 9
Customer 8 purchased 1 of Product 9
```

each thread was supposed to print out its respective arguments but instead, all three threads are printing the arguments of the last iteration.

**For some reason the problem goes away if I add a sleep() call to the bottom of the for loop but I don't want it to sleep.**

Would Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myargs` only exists until the end of the block in which it is created. When the loop pass is over, it ceases to exist, and it's undefined behaviour to access it.

Since the variable ceases to exist immediately after the thread is created, the code running in the thread attempts to access the variable after it has ceased to exist, and thus has undefined behaviour.

One solution is to extend the lifetime of the variable.

```c
ThreadArgs myargs[ NO_OF_PRODUCTS ];

for ( int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS; ++i ) {
   …
   myargs[i].… = …;
   …
   pthread_create( mythreads+i, NULL, thread_function, myargs+i )
   …
}
```

Another would be to use `malloc` to allocate the struct.

Another yet would be to ensure the thread has obtained and copied the data before moving on, which can be done through some form of synchronization.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253408/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-c-multithreading-thread-creation-in-for-loop-u); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is very narrowly targeted to the code in the question; it fails to explain the actual root cause of the problem, how to confidently identify this *class* of bugs, or how to fix them in general.

At heart, this is a [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) bug.  You have a variable

```
ThreadArgs myargs = {customer, ordered_product, ordered_quantity};
```

and you pass this variable *by reference* to a thread procedure.

```
int rc = pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, thread_function, &myargs);
```

From the moment you make this call, assuming it succeeds, there are two threads which have the ability to read *and write* to the variable.  You must somehow ensure that what one thread does with it does not *conflict* [this is an official jargon word] with what the other thread does with it.

The conflict that you actually have in your code, right now, is that the parent thread *destroys* the variable (by passing to the next iteration of the for-loop), without making sure that the child thread is done reading from it first.  However, your code would be just as broken if the variable was merely *overwritten* in the parent thread, e.g. if it was structured like this:

```
// This code is still wrong
ThreadArgs myargs;
for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS; ++i) {
   myargs.ordered_product = (rand() % NO_OF_PRODUCTS);
   myargs.ordered_quantity = (rand() % 10) + 1;
   myargs.customer = (rand() % NO_OF_CUSTOMERS);

   pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, thread_function, &myargs);
}
```

There are four general strategies for fixing bugs like this one:

1. If you need to pass just one `int` value, such as a file descriptor, or anything else that can be cast to `void *` and back without loss of information, you can pass it by value instead of by reference:

   ```
   for (;;) {
       int clientfd = accept(listenfd);
       if (clientfd >= 0) {
           pthread_t t;
           int err = pthread_create(&t, create_detached, handle_client,
                                    (void *)(intptr_t)clientfd);
           if (err) {
               log_error(err);
               close(clientfd);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Notice that you are *not* taking the address of `clientfd` in this code, you are converting its *value* to a `void *` in order to satisfy the expected argument type.  Notice also that the parent thread does *not* close clientfd unless the `pthread_create` fails.  We say that the child thread "takes ownership" of the file descriptor -- it is responsible for closing it.  The thread procedure will look something like this:

   ```
   void *handle_client(void *arg) {
       int clientfd = (int)(intptr_t)arg;
       // ... communicate with the client ...
       close(clientfd);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Put all of the data you're going to pass to the thread in a block allocated with `malloc`; free it inside the thread.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS; ++i) {
       ThreadArgs *myargs = malloc(sizeof(ThreadArgs));
       if (!myargs) {
           perror_and_exit("malloc");
       }
       myargs->ordered_product = (rand() % NO_OF_PRODUCTS);
       myargs->ordered_quantity = (rand() % 10) + 1;
       myargs->customer = (rand() % NO_OF_CUSTOMERS);

       pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, thread_function, myargs);
   }
   ```
3. If the parent thread needs access to the data passed to each thread, after that thread exits, but it *doesn't* need to touch the data while the child threads are running, this is when it's good to put the data in an array like you did with the pthread_t handles:

   ```
   pthread_t mythreads[NO_OF_THREADS];
   ThreadArgs myargs[NO_OF_THREADS];
   for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS; ++i) {
       // initialize ThreadArgs[i] here
       pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, thread_function, &myargs[i]);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS; ++i) {
       pthread_join(mythreads[i], NULL);
   }
   // at this point, and ONLY at this point, it is safe
   // for the parent thread to look at mythreads[] again
   ```
4. Finally, if it's necessary for two or more threads to access a data structure while they're both running -- if there's no way to arrange that each piece of data is only accessed by one thread during that thread's lifetime -- then you need to use some form of either locking or atomic operations.  For completeness, here is how you could use a `pthread_barrier_t` object to fix the code in your question:

   ```
   // this needs to be a global variable
   pthread_barrier_t init_barrier;

   // for loop in main:
   ThreadArgs myargs;
   pthread_barrier_init(&init_barrier, NULL, 2);
   for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_THREADS; i++) {
       myargs.ordered_product = (rand() % NO_OF_PRODUCTS);
       myargs.ordered_quantity = (rand() % 10) + 1;
       myargs.customer = (rand() % NO_OF_CUSTOMERS);

       int rc = pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, thread_function, &myargs);
       if (rc != 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create: %s\n", strerror(rc));
           exit(1);
       }
       pthread_barrier_wait(&init_barrier);
   }
   pthread_barrier_destroy(&init_barrier);

   // thread function
   void *thread_function(void *arg) {
       ThreadArgs myargs = *(ThreadArgs *)arg;
       pthread_barrier_wait(&init_barrier);
       // can safely access myargs here
   }
   ```

   (Exercise for you: Why *can't* you fix this particular instance of this problem with a mutex instead of a barrier?)